# Efficiently fill an array from a function

Tags: python, numpy, jax

I want to construct a 2D array from a function in such a way that I can utilize `jax.jit`.

The way I would normally do this using `numpy` is to create an empty array, and then fill that array in-place.

```
xx = jnp.empty((num_a, num_b))
yy = jnp.empty((num_a, num_b))
zz = jnp.empty((num_a, num_b))

for ii_a in range(num_a):
    for ii_b in range(num_b):
        a = aa[ii_a, ii_b]
        b = bb[ii_a, ii_b]

        xyz = self.get_coord(a, b)

        xx[ii_a, ii_b] = xyz[0]
        yy[ii_a, ii_b] = xyz[1]
        zz[ii_a, ii_b] = xyz[2]
```

To make this work within `jax` I have attempted to use the `jax.opt.index_update`.

```
        xx = xx.at[ii_a, ii_b].set(xyz[0])
        yy = yy.at[ii_a, ii_b].set(xyz[1])
        zz = zz.at[ii_a, ii_b].set(xyz[2])
```

This runs without errors but is very slow when I try to use a `@jax.jit` decorator (at least an order of magnitude slower than the pure python/numpy version).

What is the best way to fill a multi-dimensional array from a function using `jax`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

JAX has a [`vmap` transform](https://jax.readthedocs.io/en/latest/jax.html#vectorization-vmap) that is designed specifically for this kind of application.

As long as your `get_coords` function is compatible with JAX (i.e. is a pure function with no side-effects), you can accomplish this in one line:

```py
from jax import vmap
xx, yy, zz = vmap(vmap(get_coord))(aa, bb)
```

Comment: In order to get this to work it seems I need to explicitly add the `in_axes` like this: `jax.vmap(jax.vmap(get_coord, (None,0)), (0, None))`.

Answer (score 0):

This can be achieved efficiently by using either the [`jax.vmap`](https://jax.readthedocs.io/en/latest/jax.html#jax.vmap) or the  [`jax.numpy.vectorize`](https://jax.readthedocs.io/en/latest/jax.html#jax.numpy.vectorize) functions.

An example using `vectorize`:

```
import jax.numpy as jnp

def get_coord(a, b):
    return jnp.array([a, b, a+b])

f0 = jnp.vectorize(get_coord, signature='(),()->(i)')
f1 = jnp.vectorize(f0, excluded=(1,), signature='()->(i,j)')

xyz = f1(a,b)
```

The `vectorize` function uses `vmap` under the hood, so this should be exactly equivalent to:

```
f0 = jax.vmap(get_coord, (None, 0))
f1 = jax.vmap(f0, (0, None))
```

The advantage of using `vectorize` is that the code can be still be run in standard numpy. The disadvantage is less concise code and possibly a small amount of overhead because of the wrapper.